# How to calculate the kernel of an integral given the original function and its product

Tags: calculus, integral-equations, numerical-calculus

I am trying to solve for the kernel of the following integral.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x,t)f(t)dt = g(x)$

I know g(x) and I know f(x) but I am unsure of how I may solve for the kernal. I am trying to do this numerically. What is the best method to solve this integral equation?

Comment: Without more assumptions of some kind I don't think there is a unique solution, because you can find infinitely many solutions $\hat{K}$ such that $\int \hat{K}(x,t)f(t)dt = 0.$ Maybe you could fix the form of your kernel somehow (like $K(x,t) =  b(x)e^{-t^2}$ and just solve for $b(x)$.) If $g$ is continuous then $b(x)$ would vary continuously as well.

Comment: Complementing @1mdlrjcmed's comment, a kernel of the form $K(x,t)=g(x)F(t)$, where $F(t)$ is any function satisfying $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(t)f(t)dt=1$, is a solution to the integral equation.

Comment: @Gonçalo, maybe you should write your comment as an answer, at least until the original question is revised to give more context... and, yes, original-questioner, surely you have more conditions on the situation? Can you clarify?